# Bug Magento 2.3.4 - After disabled Temando_Shipping products page Fatal error

Tags: product, magento2.3.4

I just disabled Temando_Shipping , i am getting following error,

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface
> Temando\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Repository\PackagingRepositoryInterface
> in
> /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50
> Stack trace: #0
> /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Temando\Shippin...')
> #1 /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(167):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Temando\Shippin...')
> #2 /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(273):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array,
> 'Temando\Shippin...', NULL, 'packagingReposi...',
> 'Temando\Shippin...') #3
> /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(236):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument('Temando\Shippin...',
> Array, Ar in
> /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php
> on line 50

Comment: cache issue. Remove cache using command line and flush redis cache too

Comment: You should execute setup:di:compile as well. FYI, Temando service is not available anymore and Magento removed it as a module in Magento 2.4.

Comment: @SohelRana Shall i remove Temando_Shipping using composer, my uninstalled cmd > composer remove Temando_Shipping

Comment: @zus - on which admin page you are facing an error?

Answer (score 2):

Clear the EAV attribute that relating to Temando_Shipping because it could generate an exception Class Temando\Shipping\Model\Source\PackagingType does not exist when trying to edit product. To fix this, run the following SQL query in your database:

```
DELETE FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `source_model` LIKE '%Temando%'
```

Flush Magento Cache:

- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/*
  generated/code/*

For more detail, refer to the [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25430#issuecomment-549185323)

Comment: Shall i  remove Temando_Shipping  using composer, my uninstalled cmd > composer remove Temando_Shipping

Comment: After disable and run the cmd you given, still i am facing the issue  : https://justpaste.it/9ceq7

Comment: can you check this out if you have good knowledge of js https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320372/magento-javascript-timer-not-working

Comment: Any help, every time i run upgrade and s:c:d cmd again i am getting error, it possible to remove complete Temando module @Pratik Oza

Comment: Update 'Temando_Shipping' => 1, to 'Temando_Shipping' => 0, in app/etc/config.php